# Is it possible to query LDAP with following parameters username,serverIP,domain to check user exists

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, openldap

All the examples are using admin username and password to initialize LDAP context and making using of that context to search for the given user. I need to know if there is any means by which I can check if user exits without any dependency with admin credentials. Available paramenters: serverIP, domain, port and given username to check.Please note that given user's password is not available also.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if your LDAP server allows anonymous access.

If your LDAP server does not allow anonymous access you will need to provide a principal and a password. Normally the principal does not need to be an LDAP administrator just to search and read data.

Comment: Followup: For security, it is generally a good idea to create a user dedicated for such LDAP lookups, so you can remove all security roles from the user, except the role needed for LDAP access. This will limit your exposure if someone gains access to your app's LDAP configuration settings.

Comment: Can you please give a query to find if user exists with username

Comment: @Valath the query (filter) would be `"(uid="+username+")"` or `"(cn="+username+")"` (or whichever attribute contains your username)